# java.util.date bug?

Tags: java, jvm, java-7, java.util.date

Is there a bug is java.util.Date?  While doing some testing, I was setting the milliseconds to 
2147483647 which should give me a date of 2038-01-19 03:14:07 but it is returning 1970-01-25 20:31:23.  Also tried it with 4294967295 and get the wrong answer of 1970-02-19 17:02:47.  Does anyone know of a work around

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


/*
centos 6.3 x64
java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
*/


public class Test
{
   static public void main(String args[])
   {
      long ms = 2147483647L;

      java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date( ms );

      java.text.SimpleDateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
      // SHOULD be 2038-01-19 03:14:07
      System.out.println( df.format( d ) );         

      System.out.println(df.format(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE)));

      System.out.println( "\n" + ms );
      System.out.println( Long.MAX_VALUE );
   }
}
```

---

1970-01-25 20:31:23
292278994-08-17 07:12:55

2147483647
9223372036854775807

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2147483647 milliseconds is only about 24.8 days, so that's why it shows up as 1970-01-25 20:31:23.

4294967295 milliseconds is only about 49.7 days, so that's why it shows up as 1970-02-19 17:02:47.

You may be calculating what you expect based on 2147483647 seconds instead of milliseconds.  This is not a bug in java.util.Date; convert your seconds value to milliseconds by multiplying by 1000.

Comment: This is exactly his problem - those values correspond to seconds, given his (desired) timestamps.

Comment: Thank you... I was banging my head on the wall trying to pass c++ time_t into java.util.Date.  Once I did the math as you suggested everything works.