# Invalid conversion of long to date format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

what wrong with my code:

```
long TimeinMillisec = system.currentTimeMillis()/1000; //1376324360;

SimpleDateFormat simpledf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
String time_str = simpledf.format(TimeinMillisec);
```

time_str gives wrong value as :

```
1970-01-16_23:18:44
```

expected:

```
2013-08-12_18:19:20
```

Comment: How did you get your TimeinMillisec value?

Comment: You are [expecting wrong value](http://ideone.com/qTzdkG%5C)

Comment: @JigarJoshi Your link is broken. Change the last backslash to a forward slash

Comment: http://ideone.com/qTzdkG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This number of milliseconds (`1376324360`) is only about 15.9 days, so the date calculation looks about right.

Did you accidentally use a value in seconds?  Multiplying by 1000 gives about 43.6 years, which when added to 1970 (the base of 0 milliseconds in Java) gives 2013.

Comment: I had a feeling I had [answered something similar to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014589/java-util-date-bug/15014617#15014617) before.

Comment: So, you called your variable `TimeinMillisec`, then you got the result of the call `system.currentTimeMillis()`, then divided by 1000 to get it in seconds.  But Java will convert it the `long` value to a `Date` when formatting it, and it expects that to be a milliseconds value.  So don't divide by 1000; keep it as a milliseconds value.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I was mising long value to a Date. That  means I can also do like this: 1000*TimeinMillisec(in sec)?

Comment: Or just don't divide by 1000 in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your long value is incorrect

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss",
                                                     Locale.getDefault());
Date date= sdf.parse("2013-08-12_18:19:20");
System.out.println(date.getTime()); // out put is 1376311760000
```

equivalent mili-seconds `long` value should be `1376311760000` .

Use following and it will work fine

```
    long timeInMilliSec = 1376311760000L; // time in mili-seconds  
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
    Date date=new Date(timeInMilliSec);
    String time_str = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(time_str);
```

Comment: @user2439755 ok. you have to convert time in mile seconds to Date not seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've dropped a few 0's.  Try: 1376349560000

[Millisecond conversion tool.](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/)